# Append _ to the beginning of items in a list that start with multiple '('

Tags: list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a `list`

```
lst = ['(234A2) or (47) and 86', '(((56 or 2B2E1) and 623) and not 876) or 111']
```

I am trying to add an `_` in front of each item while preserving the `()` structure

```
['(_234A2) or (_47) and _86', '(((_56 or _2B2E1) and _623) and not _876) or _111']
```

I've tried

```
lst_split = []

for item in lst:
    lst_split = item.split()

append_lst = []
for item in lst_split:
    if item[0].isdigit():
        item = '_' + item
        append_lst.append(item)
append_lst

['_2B2E1)', '_623)', '_876)', '_111']
```

How I would add an `_` to items that start with any number of `(` and what would be a cleaner way to achieve this using list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good place to use regular expressions:

```
import re

def prefix_numbers(lst):
    return [re.sub('\d+', lambda match: '_' + match.group(), item) for item in lst]
```

Sample output:

```
>>> lst = ['(234) or (47) and 86', '(((56 or 22) and 623) and not 876) or 111']
>>> prefix_numbers(lst)
['(_234) or (_47) and _86', '(((_56 or _22) and _623) and not _876) or _111']
```

Comment: This does exactly what I asked, thanks! After I applied this I realized that some of my terms have alpha characters within them (i.e. `123A423`) which this approach yielded `_123A_423`. How would I ignore alpha characters and only append to the beginning `_123A423`? The first char is **always** a numeric value. Sorry I did not specify that, there are over 2M terms and I didn't catch it.

Comment: The `\d+` pattern matches sequences of digits, if your terms are more complicated, you could use a different pattern. Perhaps `\d\w*` or something would match your actual values (that matches a digit followed by any "word" characters, which are letters and numbers, plus underscore). You could use a character class to be more specific: `\d[A-Z0-9]` for instance would only allow numbers and capitol letters.